# Iterating over linkedlist, if statement not working

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm building a linked list that builds/tracks a movie database. In my search function I have an if statement that checks if the pointer to the title of the movie is equal to the inputted value in the search function. However, the if statement does not run even though the values are equal to each other. I didn't want to include all of my code so I included both input fields for the if statement and the loop the if statement sits in. I have validated that the values of `movieTitle` and `ptr->title` are lexically the same.

**ptr->title input**

```
printf("Name of the Movie: ");
scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", m.title);
strcpy(ptr->title, m.title);
```

**movieTitle input**

```
printf("Name of the Movie: ");
scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", movieTitle);
```

**If Statement**

```
while (ptr != NULL)
{       
    if (movieTitle == ptr->title)
    {
        printf("Year: %d\n", ptr->year);
        printf("Rating: %hhu\n", ptr->rating);
        found = true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        tmp = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "does not validate"? I can't make heads or tails of what that is supposed to mean in this context.

Comment: @AlexD I tried `stricmp`, however there is no case sensitivity.

Comment: @cpmgrat do you want case sensitivite comparison or none? there are functions for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use == to compare two strings in C

using strcmp

Something like this

```
if (strcmp( string1, string2) == 0)
```